# Error compiling GWT application (Errai)

Tags: java, gwt, errai

Can any help me understand why my application is throwing this error when running

`mvn gwt:compile`:

```
[INFO] Compiling module org.jboss.errai.ui.demo.App
[INFO]    Scanning for additional dependencies: jar:file:/home/xkm/.m2/repository/org/jboss/errai/errai-ioc/2.2.0.Final/errai-ioc-2.2.0.Final.jar!/org/jboss/errai/ioc/client/Container.java
[INFO]       Computing all possible rebind results for 'org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.QualifierEqualityFactory'
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.QualifierEqualityFactory
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.QualifierEqualityFactoryGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Extensions Bootstrapper...
[ERROR] Apr 07, 2013 1:39:10 PM org.jboss.errai.reflections.Reflections scan
[ERROR] INFO: Reflections took 1387 ms to scan 12 urls, producing 403 keys and 1809 values [using 2 cores]
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.QualifierEqualityFactory
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.QualifierEqualityFactoryGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Extensions Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.QualifierEqualityFactory
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.QualifierEqualityFactoryGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Extensions Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.QualifierEqualityFactory
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.QualifierEqualityFactoryGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Extensions Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.QualifierEqualityFactory
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.QualifierEqualityFactoryGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Extensions Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.QualifierEqualityFactory
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.QualifierEqualityFactoryGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Extensions Bootstrapper...
[INFO]       Computing all possible rebind results for 'org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Bootstrapper'
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Bootstrapper
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Extensions Bootstrapper...
[ERROR] Apr 07, 2013 1:39:11 PM org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCBootstrapGenerator generate
[ERROR] INFO: generating IOC bootstrapping class...
[ERROR] Apr 07, 2013 1:39:11 PM org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil getAllReachableClasses
[ERROR] WARNING: reachability analysis disabled. errai may generate unnecessary code.
[ERROR] Apr 07, 2013 1:39:11 PM org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil getAllReachableClasses
[ERROR] WARNING: enable reachability analysis with -Derrai.compile.perf.perform_reachability_analysis=true
[INFO]                Checking ErraiApp.properties for configured types ...
[ERROR] Apr 07, 2013 1:39:13 PM org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCBootstrapGenerator generate
[ERROR] INFO: generated IOC bootstrapping class in 1827ms (4034 beans processed)
[ERROR] Apr 07, 2013 1:39:13 PM org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCBootstrapGenerator generate
[ERROR] INFO: using IOC bootstrapping code at: /home/xkm/juno/workspace/myapp/.errai/BootstrapperImpl.java
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Bootstrapper
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Extensions Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Bootstrapper
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Extensions Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Bootstrapper
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Extensions Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Bootstrapper
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Extensions Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Bootstrapper
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Extensions Bootstrapper...
[INFO]    Scanning for additional dependencies: jar:file:/home/xkm/.m2/repository/org/jboss/errai/errai-marshalling/2.2.0.Final/errai-marshalling-2.2.0.Final.jar!/org/jboss/errai/marshalling/client/api/MarshallerFramework.java
[INFO]       Computing all possible rebind results for 'org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.MarshallerFactory'
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.MarshallerFactory
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallersGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Marshallers Bootstrapper...
[ERROR] Apr 07, 2013 1:39:13 PM org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallerGeneratorFactory generate
[ERROR] INFO: generating marshalling class...
[ERROR] Apr 07, 2013 1:39:14 PM org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallerGeneratorFactory generate
[ERROR] INFO: generated marshalling class in 583ms.
[ERROR] Apr 07, 2013 1:39:14 PM org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallersGenerator _generate
[ERROR] INFO: considering '/home/xkm/juno/workspace/myapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/' as module output path ...
[ERROR] Apr 07, 2013 1:39:14 PM org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallersGenerator _generate
[ERROR] INFO:    found '/home/xkm/juno/workspace/myapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes' output directory
[ERROR] Apr 07, 2013 1:39:15 PM org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallersGenerator _generate
[ERROR] INFO: ** deposited marshaller class in : /home/xkm/juno/workspace/myapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes
[ERROR] Apr 07, 2013 1:39:15 PM org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil getAllReachableClasses
[ERROR] WARNING: reachability analysis disabled. errai may generate unnecessary code.
[ERROR] Apr 07, 2013 1:39:15 PM org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil getAllReachableClasses
[ERROR] WARNING: enable reachability analysis with -Derrai.compile.perf.perform_reachability_analysis=true
[ERROR] Apr 07, 2013 1:39:15 PM org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallerGeneratorFactory generate
[ERROR] INFO: generating marshalling class...
[ERROR] Apr 07, 2013 1:39:15 PM org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallerGeneratorFactory generate
[ERROR] INFO: generated marshalling class in 509ms.
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.MarshallerFactory
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallersGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Marshallers Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.MarshallerFactory
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallersGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Marshallers Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.MarshallerFactory
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallersGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Marshallers Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.MarshallerFactory
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallersGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Marshallers Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.MarshallerFactory
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallersGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Marshallers Bootstrapper...
[ERROR] Apr 07, 2013 1:39:17 PM org.jboss.errai.bus.rebind.RpcProxyLoaderGenerator generate
[ERROR] INFO: generating rpc proxy loader class.
[INFO]    Scanning for additional dependencies: /home/xkm/juno/workspace/myapp/target/.generated/org/jboss/errai/ioc/client/BootstrapperImpl.java
[INFO]       Computing all possible rebind results for 'org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.BootstrapperImpl.org_jboss_errai_ui_demo_client_local_PasswordRequiredPageTemplateResource'
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.BootstrapperImpl.org_jboss_errai_ui_demo_client_local_PasswordRequiredPageTemplateResource
[INFO]             Invoking generator com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator
[INFO]                Creating assignment for getContents()
[INFO]                   Finding resources
[INFO]                      [ERROR] Resource org/jboss/errai/ui/demo/client/local/PasswordRequiredPage.html not found. Is the name specified as Class.getResource() would expect?
[INFO]       [WARN] For the following type(s), generated source was never committed (did you forget to call commit()?)
[INFO]          [WARN] org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.BootstrapperImpl_org_jboss_errai_ui_demo_client_local_PasswordRequiredPageTemplateResource_default_InlineClientBundleGenerator
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in '/home/xkm/juno/workspace/myapp/target/.generated/org/jboss/errai/ioc/client/BootstrapperImpl.java'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 149:  Failed to resolve 'org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.BootstrapperImpl.org_jboss_errai_ui_demo_client_local_PasswordRequiredPageTemplateResource' via deferred binding
[ERROR] Apr 07, 2013 1:39:21 PM org.jboss.errai.databinding.rebind.BindableProxyLoaderGenerator generate
[ERROR] INFO: generating bindable proxy loader class.
[ERROR] Apr 07, 2013 1:39:21 PM org.jboss.errai.enterprise.rebind.JaxrsProxyLoaderGenerator generate
[ERROR] INFO: generating jax-rs proxy loader class.
[INFO]    [ERROR] Cannot proceed due to previous errors
```

Looking deeply at the code I can see:

```
[ERROR] Resource org/jboss/errai/ui/demo/client/local/PasswordRequiredPage.html not found. Is the name specified as Class.getResource() would expect?
```

However the html page is there with the corresponding PasswordRequiredPage.java:

**PasswordRequiredPage.java**:

```
@Dependent
@Templated("#passwordrequired")
@Page
public class PasswordRequiredPage extends Composite {
}
```

**PasswordRequiredPage.html**:

```
<div data-field="passwordrequired">
 <!-- Content -->
</div>
```

What could have gone wrong in my application? I've done:

```
 - mvn clean (SUCCESS)
 - mvn gwt:compile (FAIL)
 - mvn gwt:run (FAILE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you have `PasswordRequiredPage.html` in the same folder that you have `PasswordRequiredPage.java`, it should be in the class-path when the gwt-compiler is running.

You can fix it in two ways:

1. Copy `PasswordRequiredPage.html` to the folder where the java compiler generates the `PasswordRequiredPage.class`, it is done configuring the [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) (goal copy-resources)
2. Add the source folder where the `.html` is to your compile class-path.

I've never used Errai and dont know how it uses the gwt compiler, but for some reason it is adding .java files to the classpath (probabely .css and .png as well) but no .html files.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I will try this. I'm using JBoss Errai coz it really makes my UI design so easy that I can use the usual HTML, JS + CSS templates... anyway, would you mind also checking this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874698/handling-un-mapped-rest-path

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but as far as i know you should use the **id** attribute in HTML for templating. The data-field is used for injecting widgets or construction elements in the corresponding java code to have handles on them.

Try

```
<div id="passwordrequired">
 <!-- Content -->
</div>
```

In java code "this" will then correspond to the root widget / composite.