# Handling un-mapped Rest path

Tags: java, regex, servlets, jax-rs, guice

This is my current Guice configuration:

```
public class MyServletModule extends ServletModule {
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        bind(MyRest.class);
        serveRegex(".+(?<!\\.(html|css|png|jpg))")
               .with(HttpServletDispatcher.class);
    }
}
```

However I want that my Rest resource is only access in form of `http://127.0.0.1:8888/{hashcode_or_filename}` and the only form accepted and processed (well, plus the /create method below).

Right now, I can deal with hashcode and filename properly in this path pattern.

However I am not sure how to deal the kind or scenario below, where the client is requesting path that is not mapped, which returns this in my case:

> Could not find resource for relative : /examples/foo of full path:
>   `http://127.0.0.1:8888/examples/foo`

or

> Could not find resource for relative : /examples/bar/foo of full
>   path: `http://127.0.0.1:8888/examples/bar/foo`

What I need is to be able to be able to handle unmapped paths so I can return a error HTML page or something and not show these error text in the browser.

Also if the request is: `http://127.0.0.1:8888/` I need to forward to `http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html` automatically. As right now I have to manually put the index.html in the tail.

My Resteasy resource is configure or wired with just:

```
@Singleton
@Path("/")
public class MyRest {
    @GET
    @Path({hashcode})
    public Response getSomething(...){}

    @POST
    @Path("create")
    public Response createSomething(...){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to register filter to handle responses with error code other that 200 (OK). Or add to your web.xml something like this:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

> Also if the request is: `http://127.0.0.1:8888/` I need to forward to
>   `http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html` automatically. As right now I have to
>   manually put the index.html in the tail.

You can use this module http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

**WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>confPath</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!--...omitted...-->
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

**WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite
        PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN"
        "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">
<urlrewrite>
    <rule match-type="regex">
        <from>^/$</from>
        <to type="redirect">/index.html</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```